# Certain Soundcloud stream_urls are not being resolved

Tags: soundcloud

I have tested the following request on browser and mobile, and I am unable to stream: `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/173752179/stream?client_id=XXX`

Is it common for top songs to be un-streamable?  Are some songs inherently buggy? The song is currently at the top of Soundcloud's popular music section (Skrillex And Diplo), if that matters.  I want to add the Soundcloud API to my app but I am hesitant if bugs such as this are common.  Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: you should be able to stream it. are you using the api correctly? can you post your code?

Comment: I'm playing around with the browser to get a feel for the API first (so no real code yet) All other tested track IDs work for me except that one.  Does it work when you use your client_id?

Comment: I get a blank page when using that web address are you sure its proper?

Comment: I think that number after the /track/ isn't right. Are you sure you are getting the proper track id for that link. What link are you trying to get?

Comment: So I used this link to listen to the track you are talking about -> https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/193270658/stream?client_id=xxx  So you must have the track id wrong. If you don't know already you can get the proper track id when you click on the song and click the share embed and look at the link there.

Comment: Interesting - how would you obtain this ID programatically?  I extracted the ID from `https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/explore/popular%20music` (the first result) and it appears to be incorrect on the first track, but works for the rest (at least the ones I test).  Also if you go to `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/173752179?client_id=XXX` track info that appears to be correct is displayed

Comment: Ahh so now that I know what track you are trying to get I understand the problem now. You are right there is a problem with that particular song. You cant even play that song via soundcloud let alone the api. These issues are rare, its possible that the artist removed that song or something to cause this. You are also right in getting the id from that feed typically through code you could search based on artist or something and get a json object back and sort that for the id. Soundcloud is amazing and super cool so don't let this stop you from integrating it. The only problem I found was....

Comment: it uses flash and a flash player. So it made it difficult to create my own SC player.

Comment: I listen to a lot of music on soundcloud and from time to time I find some songs or even full artists don't work. It usually doesn't last long but it may be a data indexing thing on their end.

Comment: Glad to know its just a minor hiccup then, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some artists have elected to have their tracks only playable via the official soundcloud site and apps. Unfortunately for API consumers, the only way you can tell that a track is unplayable is to try to resolve the stream url to see if you get a 404 or a 302 (redirect to the audio file).

```
$ curl -I https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/173752179/stream\?client_id\=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```